# MySQL complex multi table count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, aggregate-functions

In MySQL I'm trying to get the amount of rows in `forum_posts`, where the id equals the `post_id` column in `forum_posts_threads`, where the `thread_id` column equals the `thread_id` column in `forum_threads_forums`, where the `forum_id` column matches a certain value. To illustrate:

`forum_forums`

```
id  name
1   forum1
2   forum2
```

`forum_threads`

```
id  title
1   thread1
2   thread2
```

`forum_threads_forums`

```
thread_id  forum_id
1          1
1          2
2          2
```

`forum_posts`

```
id  title
1   post1
2   post2
```

`forum_posts_threads`

```
post_id  thread_id
1        1
2        1
2        2
```

Then I'm executing a query which gets all forums. What I would like, is for it to count the amount of posts in each forum.

So, it would need to return something like this:

```
id  name    post_count
1   forum1  2
2   forum2  3
```

I already have the following query:

```
SELECT
    forum_forums.id,
    forum_forums.name,
    forum_forums.description,
    COUNT(forum_threads_forums.thread_id) AS thread_count,
    forum_categories.id AS category_id,
    forum_categories.name AS category_name,
    forum_categories.description AS category_description
FROM
    forum_forums
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forum_threads_forums
ON
    forum_forums.id=forum_threads_forums.forum_id
INNER JOIN
    forum_forums_categories
ON
    forum_forums.id=forum_forums_categories.forum_id
INNER JOIN
    forum_categories
ON
    forum_forums_categories.category_id=forum_categories.id
GROUP BY
    forum_forums.id
```

The query is already able to count the amount of threads (and do some other stuff), but I'm unsure how to count posts since it needs to check for a condition in two seperate tables.

So if anyone could give some advice as to how to adjust my query that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you replace "table 1", "table 2", etc. in the first paragraph with the actual table names, your question would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @Tom I will, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are trying to count the number of posts with threads in forum_threads_forums.  There are a couple ways you could do this.

The easiest way would probably just be to join to the forum_posts_threads table and do a `COUNT DISTINCT` on post_id.  You would also have to change your thread_count to do a `COUNT DISTINCT` due to Cartesians.

```
SELECT
    forum_forums.id,
    forum_forums.name,
    forum_forums.description,
    COUNT(DISTINCT forum_threads_forums.thread_id) AS thread_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts_threads.post_id) AS post_count,
    forum_categories.id AS category_id,
    forum_categories.name AS category_name,
    forum_categories.description AS category_description
FROM
    forum_forums
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forum_threads_forums
ON
    forum_forums.id=forum_threads_forums.forum_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    forum_posts_threads
ON
    forum_threads_forums.thread_id=forum_posts_threads.thread_id
INNER JOIN
    forum_forums_categories
ON
    forum_forums.id=forum_forums_categories.forum_id
INNER JOIN
    forum_categories
ON
    forum_forums_categories.category_id=forum_categories.id
GROUP BY
    forum_forums.id
```

If there is some criteria you need to apply to the forum_posts table, you would instead add a subquery in your `SELECT` clause.  Something like this (add in your `WHERE` clause below).  It would refer to the forum_threads_forums.thread_id from your main `FROM` clause.

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT forum_posts.post_id ) post_count
 FROM   forum_posts
        JOIN forum_post_threads ON forum_posts.post_id = forum_post_threads.post_id
 WHERE  forum_post_threads.thread_id = forum_threads_forums.thread_id
        [ADD IN YOUR ADDITIONAL WHERE CONDITIONS]
) as post_count
```